# Need some assistance understanding a SQL Server 2012 query plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
Select TOP 5000
    CdCl.SubId
From dbo.PanelCdCl CdCl WITH (NOLOCK)
    Inner Join dbo.PanelHistory PH ON PH.SubId = CdCl.SubId
Where CdCl.PanelCdClStatusId IS NULL And PH.LastProcessNumber >= 1605
Order By CdCl.SubId
```

The query plan looks as follows:

[image]

Both the PanelCdCl and PanelHistory tables have a clustered index / primary key on SubId, and it's the only column in the index. There is exactly one row for each SubId in each table. Both tables have ~35M total rows in them.

I'm curious why the query plan is showing a clustered index scan on PanelHistory when the join is being done on the clustered index column.

Comment: Probably because of the other filters?

Comment: It seems right to me.  What would you expect it to do?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - My clustered index / primary key on PanelHistory is on the SubId column. Why would it scan the clustered index looking for the SubId instead of doing a seek?

Comment: I'll post as an answer ..

Comment: Because it also has to find ProcessNumber values in a certain range. Depending on how many there are, a scan might be more efficient.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - As I said in my post, there is only a single row in the PanelHistory table for any given SubId (my clustered index is on SubId alone). So either the single row has the desired process number or it doesn't.

Comment: How is the non clustered index `IX_PanelCdCl_PanelCdCl...` on `PanelCdCl` defined?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - It's an index on the PanelCdClStatusId column with SubId as an INCLUDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not scanning PanelHistory's clustered index(SubId) to find a SubId, it's scanning on it to find all rows where `LastProcessNumber >= 1605`.  This is the first logical step.

Then it likewise scans PanelCdCl to find all non-null `PanelCdClStatusId` rows.  Then since they had the same index (SubId), they are both already sorted on the Join column, so it can do a Merge-Join without an additional sort.  (Merge-Join is almost always the most efficient if it doesn't have to re-sort the input rows).

Then it doesn't have to do a Sort for the ORDER BY, because it's already in `SubId` order.

And finally, it does the TOP, which has to be after everything else (by the rules of SQL clause logical execution ordering).

So the only place it tests `SubId` values is in the Merge-Join, it never pushes it down to the scans.  This would probably remain true if it did a Hash-Join instead.  Only for a Nested-Loop Join would it have to push the `SubId` test down as a seek on a table, and that should only be the lower branch, not the upper one.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand you correctly, once SQL Server has done the join (which I presume will be on the clustered index), it scans the rows satisfying the join looking for rows where the process number >= 1605. If so, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @RandyMinder I have updated my answer.  Let me know if that does not answer your question...

Comment: Now I'm a bit more confused than before. So are you saying it will scan all 35M rows in PanelHistory, looking for LastProcessNumber >= 1605 and then it compares the SubId's found with the SubIds from PanelCdCl?

Answer (score 1):

The merge join operator needs two sorted inputs. The clustered key is `SubId` in both tables which means that the scan in `PanelHistory` will give the rows in correct order. The clustered key is included in all non clustered key indexes so because of that you will have all rows in NCI `IX_PanelCdCl_PanelCdClStatusId` where `PanelCdClStatusId is null` ordered by `SubId` as well so that can also be used directly by the merge join.

What you see here is actually two scans, one of the clustered key in `PanelHistory` with a residual predicate on `LastProcessNumber > 1605` and one index range scan in `IX_PanelCdCl_PanelCdClStatusId` as long as `PanelCdClStatusId is null`.

They will however not scan the entire table/index. The query is executed from left to right in the query plan where `select` is asking for one row at a time until there is no more rows to be had. That means that the top operator will stop asking for new rows from the merge join when it has the required 5000 rows.